# Difference between "dadurch" and "deshalb"

Tags: difference, adverb

I wrote the following sentece:

> **Deshalb** geht sie oft ins Ausland.

But I was corrected and told that the right way to say it would be:

> **Dadurch** geht sie oft ins Ausland.

What is the different in these 2 adverbs? How could I know which one to say in every sentence?

Comment: Usually _deshalb_ and _dadurch_ are interchangeable. Can you give more context to the sentence from your question? Maybe we can tell then, why _dadurch_ is the preferred word to use in this case.

Comment: I cannot really remember what the context was, since I was kinda lost in the conversation :P Could you maybe give me 2 different contexts, where each of them are used?

Comment: Spontaneously I'd say "deshalb" is more flexible to use than "dadurch" so I wonder what context that was when dadurch is preferred over deshalb.

Answer (score 6):

»Deshalb« means always »for that reason«, »dadurch« **can** have this meaning.

Example for this meaning:

> Die Firma, für die sie arbeitet, unterhält lebhafte internationale
>   Beziehungen. **Deshalb / Dadurch** geht sie oft ins Ausland.
>   *(The company she works for has lively international relationships. That's why she often goes abroad.)*

But »dadurch« can also mean »by / through the means of«.

> Wortlos legte er den Herren ein Dokument vor. **Dadurch** beantwortete er die Frage.
>   *(Without a word he presented a document to the gentlemen. By this means he answered the question.)*

Comment: I would go a step further and say that the second meaning (by/through the means of) is the primary one.

Comment: @RHa: Hard to say, I didn't start a ranking anyway.